# python check for matlab installation

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to know if there is a way I could check from my python code if matlab exists on a system. So far the only thing I can come up with is: `exists = os.system("matlab")` and then parse the exists for a `command not found`. But I'm almost sure this will:

1. Start matlab in case it exists on the system. I don't want this.
2. The response may vary depending on the system I'm running ?

So is there any way I could check if a matlab installation is available on the system from python ?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your system call works, you can check the path for matlab.exe like this:

```
import os

def matlab_installed():
    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(";"):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, "matlab.exe")):
            return True
    return False
```

For Unix, you have to change split(";") to split(":") and "matlab.exe" to whatever the matlab executable is called under Unix.

Comment: Ok your solution works on Windows OS. However on MacOS the os.environ["PATH"] return only /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin when the actual PATH if done by echo $PATH in terminal is: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:.... etc.

Comment: That's an environment issue, os.environ["PATH"] returns the same as echo $PATH on my fedora box. How do you call python?

Comment: Ok problem was on MacOS I was starting the app from Aptana Studio. Seems that if I start from terminal I get the required input. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to to use ***shutil***

```
import shutil
mt = shutil.which("matlab")
```

If 'matlab' is found it returns the path where it was found, else it returns 'NoneType'. You may check for 'matlab' or 'matlab.exe' depending on the OS.